# How to keep the first item invisible before I click the screen?

Tags: beamer, framed, overlays, covers

See the picture. The current situation is that the frame title and the first item appears at the same time.

But I only want to let the frame title visible at first, and after I click the screen, the first item turn to be visible.

How could I do that? Be grateful with any hints!

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Maths Blocks}
\begin{theorem}<1->[Pythagoras]
$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
\end{theorem}
\begin{corollary}<3->
$ x + y = y + x  $
\end{corollary}
\begin{proof}<2->
$\omega +\phi = \epsilon $
\end{proof}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the overlay specifications from `<1->` to `<2->` etc. (i.e. increment the number of all the starting slides by 1), then the first slide of the frame will only contain the frame title.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Maths Blocks}
\begin{theorem}<2->[Pythagoras]  % changed from 1 to 2
$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
\end{theorem}
\begin{corollary}<4->   % changed from 3 to 4
$ x + y = y + x  $
\end{corollary}
\begin{proof}<3->   % changed from 2 to 3
$\omega +\phi = \epsilon $
\end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, after adding <2->, It achieves what I want.   \begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@->] 
\item<2-> $z=\frac{2+4i}{i}=-(2+4i)=4-2i$ One more thing, I find a small problem. But the alert color turns to be black. Before adding, the color of current item is red, it turns to be black after next item(of course, the next item is red from transparent). How could I keep this? Thanks!

Comment: @Hinn I don't know exactly, why don't you create a new question about that.

Comment: T. I find that problem after adding your advice. It might be not good to ask these small question. It looks a little bit stupid... haha